# Grails service class cross ref

Tags: grails, service

I realize that Grails service classes are Spring managed singletons. I also know that you can reference one service class from another by just declaring a local def with the serviceClassName in camel case like that.  What surprised me was that I can't seem to cross reference service classes together like so

```
 class FirstService {

   def secondService
 ...
 }

 class SecondService {

   def firstService
 ...
 }
```

Is this true for everyone, or did I mess up somewhere in the ... section?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grails isn't able to inject when there are circular references. You should actually be getting an exception along the lines of `FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet`. There's a JIRA issue about this where they stated they won't be fixing this, as it's more to do with Spring than Grails (http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5080)

However, there is a workaround that is cited in the JIRA and I can verify does work with Grails 2.0.RC1. In SecondService, make it `protected def firstService` and add `def grailsApplication` below that and then add the method `def initialize() { this.firstService = grailsApplication.mainContext.firstService }`. Lastly, in BootStrap.groovy, add `def firstService` and then in the `init` closure, add `secondService.initialize()`. Not a pretty solution, but this will get everything hooked up the way you want it.

Comment: Todd, did you mean `def secondService` on Bootstrap?

Comment: No, because the ```def firstService``` will cause that to be injected into the application context, so then when initialize is run on secondService, it will be able to retrieve firstService from the ```grailsApplication.mainContext```