# How to initialize two grails service classes referencing each other

Tags: spring, grails, service, javabeans, init

I have a grails application where there are two service classes say X and Y. Y has reference to X and X has reference to Y. So, while running app, it says `Error creating bean with name '<service class name>': org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet`

I know if i dereference any one of the bean from other it will work but that would require some code modifications which i dont want to do at this point. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: This is an issue of circular reference related to Spring and not specific to Grails. Follow this [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002951/grails-service-class-cross-ref) for work around.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction...

Comment: Well you could find workaround for this issue, but it's bad design to use circular references in your app.